# angularjs ng-blur on field when nothing is entered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and I am trying to create a form page with some animations.
I am trying to tweak the code from fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/atXAC/11/

```
<div ng-class="{'active':hasFocus==true,'inactive':hasFocus==false}">Enter     your Name here</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="user.name" ng-click="hasFocus=true" ng-customblur="onBlur()" required id="name"/>
```

Currently, on click and on click away the css class is changed. 
What i am trying to do is when something is entered in the box the class should not change. If the text box is empty then only the class should be changed on- click-away. How do i do this? any help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correct,your Controller should be like this.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.onBlur = function(){  
    if(user.name=="")
        $scope.hasFocus = false;
    }
}
```